# How to handle numeric strings with different decimal symbols like a comma instead of period in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, decimal, symbols

We have many VB.net programs (all years) that were written for US customers.  We are now getting some international customers that use the period (dot) as decimal separator instead of a comma (i.e. the comma separates dollars from cents and the period separates 3 decimal places).

We can get the decimal separator character from the Registry here:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Control Panel\International", "sShortDate"
```

So we know what it is. The issue is with the various VB functions. Given a string using a comma separator:

```
s = "1.234,56"
```

This is a valid numeric string, where `IsNumeric(s)` returns true, but `Val(s)` returns `1` instead of `1234.56`. `cDBL(s)` does return `1234.56` correctly.

With hundreds of Val's and IsNumeric's throughout our apps, we have all kinds of conversion issues. How can we parse these values correctly?

The above was using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: How does the app not work. Does it not compile or does it not generate the required output

Comment: .NET already does this by itself, starting at .NET 4.0.  Feel better about it by trying it, use Control Panel's Language applet to change the setting.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a mix of IsNumeric() and Val(), you can use [Double.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2), and the TryParse methods for other numerical types, to which you can supply culture info to use when parsing the number.

You could use the [CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentuiculture?view=netframework-4.7.2) to get the culture info to use.

Comment: There are hundreds in each program. Will take a lot of work.

Comment: @QuickBooksDev You will at have the satisfaction afterwards of having reduced the technical debt and gaining more happy customers. Jeff Atwood wrote a blog article about it: [Paying Down Your Technical Debt](https://blog.codinghorror.com/paying-down-your-technical-debt/)

Answer (score 1):

`Val()` and `IsNumeric()` only exist for backwards compatibility with older vb6-era code. You shouldn't really use them in newer apps. (The `CDbl()` operator and similar really are operators, even though they have function semantics, and are still okay, though I personally tend towards the `Convert.ToX()` family of functions).

Instead, use the newer .Net APIs: `Integer.Parse()`, `Integer.TryParse()`, `Integer.ParseExact()`, and `Integer.TryParseExact()`. This family of functions is available for all the built-in numeric types (`Integer`, `Double`, `Decimal`, `Long`, `ULong`, etc). Especially look at the functions with "Exact" in the name, which allow you to specify the expected formats of the input string, as well as an object indicating the culture to use for the decimal separator.

Comment: The new functions do not do the same thing as Val.  Val converted the numerics up until a non-numeric so
Val("123 ABC") would produce a double with the value of 123.

Comment: Which is why the functions are still there are not just removed, but really, it's a very strange thing to expect a string like "123 ABC" to convert cleanly. I'd want to clean up the string anyway, and make sure it matches the kind of you input you expect.